# Block REST API on Parse-Server

Tags: parse-server

Is there a way to block REST calls for all or certain classes, so that I only allow cloud calls in Parse-Server?

I'm using Parse-Server 2.3.8 (and hoping to upgrade soon).

Answer (score 0):

You can add CLPs and ACLs.

CLP is Class Level Permissions. These get applied to the entire table.

ACL is Access Control Level, and applies to an individual object.

Using these you control the ability to read ( get - fetch if you have the object id, find - querying for the object) or write (create - to create new objects, update - change the data, delete - delete the object) or even add fields to the table.

When a user performs an operation on an object, they must first pass the CLP, and then the ACL for the object.  So, if your table does not have public read and write access, but your ACL provides read and write access to a specific user, they still won't be able to read or write that object, since they don't pass the CLP.

You can customize these permissions for Public (anyone, with or without a signed in user), a specific User, or a specific Role.  There is also the concept of Pointer permissions.  Say you have a Comments table with an Author field that is a Parse User.  You can have public read access for the comment, but no public write permissions, and give the Author pointer write permissions.  This basically means that the Author is implicitly added to the ACL of every object.

Note that requests with the master key ignore all CLP / ACLs - they can modify anything.

So, to answer your question, in the dashboard, go to each class you want to block requests on, press the security button at the top, and disable public read/write permissions.  On this little window with the permissions, you can click the gear icon to do more fine grained permissions (get, find, update, delete, create), whereas the "simple" view will be only read/write.

Here's some relevant documentation: http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#security

Comment: Blocking access on a CLP or ACL level would affect both the REST API as well as the cloud functions. What I'm trying to achieve is allowing only cloud calls. That way I have full control over who is accessing the data, and I can easily hide / show sensitive fields based on the request.user.

It would be similar to having a beforeGet / beforeFind function.

Comment: Well yeah that's the idea. In cloud functions, all API calls are made by default with no permissions, so same as public read/write. But your cloud functions can pass the master key to override all permissions or even pass the current user's session token to be able to access those things based on the user.  Or, you wouldn't even need to - Wrap the "sensitive" fields in an object that gets stored as a pointer on a base object.  The senstiive fields object would have stricter permissions, so a person may be able to see the base object but not the sensitive fields object.

Comment: Also, be careful about what "sensitive" fields you're storing - There are laws about how you need to store certain types of data!  If this is payment information or things like an SSN, I would look into an option that isn't storing it on your own database.